# Pagination crashes the front-end layer.

Tags: java, spring

I try to write web app in Java (Spring Boot) displaying the content on many subsites (like this one https://kwejk.pl/). When I try to create pagination system using parameters located in a link (uri), the front-end layer crashes (not only on sites where the parameters are used).

https://github.com/ToTomki/getinpoland/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/getinpoland/controller/MainController.java

I uploaded screenshot to visualize what I mean. The first image shows what happens when the commented part of code from my github is commented. The second one - when that part of code is uncommented.

Can you help me to solve the problem? :)

http://s2.ifotos.pl/img/withcodej_qnseqxr.jpg
http://s5.ifotos.pl/img/withoutco_qnseqxp.jpg

Comment: If you can find an error I might be able to help.

Comment: If I know what crashes front-end, I would not write here :(

Comment: Is there something in the developer console in google chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@GetMapping(name="/explore")
```

to one of the following:

```
@GetMapping(path="/explore")
@GetMapping(value="/explore")
@GetMapping("/explore")
```

After changing it, your project starts to work properly. Using name here is wrong as it is just assigning a name to the mapping instead of binding url with the handler method. It's difficult to say why it causes your css not load though.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution is correct and everything works fine! :)